# Site not resizing nor reorienting on mobile

Tags: mobile

My site isn't resizing or reorienting on mobile. I tried putting

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
```

in the code, but that didn't help.

Is there an easy way to have a site reorient itself on mobile and fit itself on mobile regardless of the orientation?

I've read several posts on this topic, but the solutions don't seem to be working for me.

Comment: We'd need to see your CSS, these things don't happen magically.

Comment: Sorry about that...http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/test

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries with `max-width`.

```
@media(max-width:479px){
    //css rules for mobile here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your site should adjust according to orientation.

See here are different media queries you can put in:

Eg iPhone5:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) { 
//your css style
}
```

Use (orientation:landscape) or (orientation:portrait) and do the css edits accordingly.

I'm unsure whether you have designed your site with 'fluid layouts' and 'fluid images'.